# How many logic gates does it take to implement base-100 addition?

Tags: circuit-design, adder, decimal, computer-arithmetic

I'm curious about the trade-offs that have been made in implementing different kinds of arithmetic in different models of computers, to which I'm trying to understand what the costs of various options would be.

Say you want to implement base-100, using 7 bits to store a decimal number from 0-99. So you want an adder circuit that takes a pair of 7-bit inputs and produces a 7-bit output (still 0-99) plus a carry flag.

How many logic gates would this take, roughly, compared to the obvious alternatives of either 7-bit binary or 8-bit BCD?

Comment: It really isn't a question of the number of gates required in the ALU -- which really doesn't change much in the options you've outlined -- but rather, the other operations you might need to do on those numbers. You need to take a higher-level systems view of the kind of data you need to process, how you get that data into and out of the system, and the kinds of operations you need to do on it.

Comment: @DaveTweed Okay, what other operations are required? Converting to and from decimal for I/O, is certainly much easier with base-100 than binary (albeit slightly more difficult than with BCD).

Comment: Using 7-bits to store a...number from 0-99 isn't "base-100." That would just be straight-up _binary_. Now, if you used an _additional_ seven bits to represent the N*100 place (where 0<=N<100), and maybe seven more bits after that for the N*10000 place, then we would be talking about what might be called "binary-coded base-100 notation."

Comment: Well, take storage, for example. How many base-100 numbers do you need to store? Compared to pure binary, BCD requires 20% more bits, and base-100 requires 5% more bits. Same thing for bus widths throughout the machine. Gate count is rarely the driving factor in choices like these.

Comment: I don't see how converting base-100 to base-10 is significantly easier than converting 7-bit binary to base-10. In base-100 you have 100 different symbols, each represented by a 7-bit binary value. You have to convert these 100 symbols to 100 sets of two BCD values...you are still mapping a 7-bit binary value to an 8-bit, 2-digit, BCD representation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Right, but compare e.g. converting a 63-bit binary number to base 10, versus converting nine 7-bit base-100 numbers to base 10.

Comment: But that's not the situation you described in your question, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think computation mod 2ⁿ + carry of 2ⁿ first, and comparing the result to 10ᵏ to control a "correction step" obvious - and clumsy.
Establish carry C of 10ᵏ first, and let that control a third summand for the low bits.
Add that in using "carry save adders". This leaves a problem where there is the carry from the *most significant CSA* as well as from adding the low part - standard solution: *plaster the way to MSB with half adders*.

Check for a carry of 10² where adding a+b? :
Get rid of some symmetry:
B (both) = bitwise AND of a and b
O (one) = bitwise OR of a and b
C = B6 + O6B5 + O6O5(O4+O3+O2+B1+O1B0)

How to add in another 28 without undue increase in delay or circuitry?
Good news is the two least significant bits could go right to a/the standard two-operand adder.
In addition this calls for one full adder for each of three 1-bits representing 28, and a half adder for every one of two remaining bits:
about 3 FAs + 2 HAs.
(Along these lines, single digit "decimal adjust" needs 2FAs+1HA, 2 digits 4FAs+2HAs, 3 digits 6FAs+3HAs; "millennial adjust" 2FAs+6HAs.
6 digits centennial 9FAs+6HAs, millennial 4FAs+12HAs. As each FA is about twice as complex as a HA, 24 vs. 20.
But this is unfair on centennial adjust:
subtracting 4 and adding 32 may well use less circuitry than adding 4, 8, & 16)

Counting *gates*(even switches/transistors) is academic until taking into account circumstances like limited fan-in and fan-out.

Comment: One of the first microprocessors, the MP944, is reported to have used 20 bits, the 1952 IAS machine 40, several Cray designs 60: anybody for exploring "decimal" arithmetic on these machines? (I can find reason for none of these going beyond (packed) BCD, if that.)